# How to test if there is a word in the sentence with cypress?

Tags: cypress

I am trying to figure out a way to test a sentence.

let say there is an array of pet

```
let pet = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']
```

and there is a sentence which may contain one of the value

```
let sentense = 'John adopt a {oneofthepet} last night'
```

Normally I write something like this to test the words

```
sentense.should('have.text', 'John adopt a dog last night')
```

but I want to test all three possible scenarios for the pet array and if 1 of them is correct I want to pass the test

```
 sentense.should('have.text', 'John adopt a dog last night')
 sentense.should('have.text', 'John adopt a cat last night')
 sentense.should('have.text', 'John adopt a bird last night')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Do a for each loop and check the presence of the pet. word in the sentence using the `if` condition. Once that condition is found, write the equivalent `should` assertion to make the test pass.

```js
pet.forEach((pet) => {
  if (sentence.toLowerCase().includes(pet)) { //Assuming sentence contains string like John adopt a dog last night
    sentence.should('have.text', 'John adopt a dog last night') //add the assertion
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is useful for you.

You can inject each pet into the basic sentence.

```js
const possibleSentences = pets.map(pet => `John adopt a ${pet} last night`)
sentence.should('be.oneOf', possibleSentences)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a regular expression you can match any from a list of pets.

Using `.should('match', ...)` compares the regex pattern to your actual value.

```js
let sentence = 'John adopt a cat last night'
cy.wrap(sentence).should('match', /John adopt a (dog|cat|rat) last night/)  // pass

let sentence = 'John adopt a dog last night'
cy.wrap(sentence).should('match', /John adopt a (dog|cat|rat) last night/)  // pass
```

or dynamically

```js
const pets = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']
conts petOptions = pets.join('|')  // gives you "dog|cat|bird"

const petRegex = new RegExp(`John adopt a (${petOptions}) last night')
cy.wrap(sentence).should('match', petRegex)
```